# Trying to match on room

Tags: php, mysql, match

Hi StackOverflow members,

I'm trying to fix some code of a friend, but i'm not getting out of it. We have made one step to it, but it's not the exact order. Let me explain first.

We want to create a match system. But not on user-base but on actual room base. The matches are made by max-rent, minimum square meters and the city of choice.

Now we have created the following code, which outputs every user, with it's matched rooms.

```
$members = $db->query("Select g.gFirstname, g.gLastname,g.gEmail, v.vMeter, v.vMaxrent, v.vWhen, v.vCity From users as g LEFT JOIN users_pref as v ON(g.gId=v.vGid)");

$count = $members->num_rows;

while($fetch = $members->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<br /><br />';
    echo 'Rooms found for: <strong>'.stripslashes($fetch['gFirstname']).' '.stripslashes($fetch['gLastname']).'</strong><br /><br />';
    $selectKamers = $db->query("Select * From rooms Where kWhen >= ".$fetch['vWhen']." AND kCity = ".$fetch['vCity']." AND kMeter >= '".$fetch['vMeter']."' AND kMaxrent <= ".$fetch['vMaxrent']."");

    while($kamer = $selectKamers->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<h1>'.$kamer['kStreet'].' '.$kamer['kHomenumber'].'</h1>';
    }
}
```

This code as i said, first shows all users, and in a column below each users, shows every room the user applied that matches his preferences.

Now the problem is. We want to create the function to show all rooms, and below that all users that matches with that room.

Maybe it's because of lack of insight, but can someone maybe help me on the road how i could try to achieve this?

My database tables are as following:

```
--users
gId | gFistname | gLastname | gEmail
1   | Bob       | Hope      | Email
2   | John      | Doe       | Email

--users_pref
vGid | vMeter | vMaxrent | vWhen  | vCity
1    | 10     | 400      | time() | cityId
2    | 20     | 500      | time() | cityId

--rooms
kWhen  | kStreet | kHomenumber | kMeter | kMaxrent | kCity 
time() | street  | 100         | 15     | 300      | cityid
time() | street  | 200         | 25     | 400      | cityid
```

i tried to be as complete as possible with my explanation if i miss anything, please let me know.

Many thanks in advance!

Kevin.

Comment: Did you see LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: I don't understand what the left join on line 1 has anything to do with it. I cannot change users_pref to rooms, because there's no connecting id between the tables users and rooms..

Comment: What is the PRIMARY KEY on the preferences table and the rooms table?

Comment: The primary key in the preferences table is "vId" in rooms it is "kId"
But there's no connection between those two.. the preferences table is for the users. and connected to the users database by vGid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,firstname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,lastname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,email VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1   ,'Bob','Hope','Email1'),
(2   ,'John','Doe','Email2');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_preferences;

CREATE TABLE user_preferences
( user_id INT NOT NULL 
, city_id INT NOT NULL
, date  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
, meter INT NOT NULL
, maxrent INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(user_id,city_id,date)
);

INSERT INTO user_preferences VALUES
(1,1,'time()',10,400),      
(2,1,'time()',20,500);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rooms;

CREATE TABLE rooms
(city_id INT NOT NULL
,street VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,homenumber INT NOT NULL
,date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,meter INT NOT NULL
,maxrent INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(city_id,street,homenumber)
);

INSERT INTO rooms VALUES
(1,'street',100,'time()',15,300),
(1,'street',200,'time()',25,400);
```

To get a list of all rooms together with any compatible users, we can do this...

```
SELECT r.*,u.* 
  FROM rooms r 
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_preferences ru 
    ON ru.city_id = r.city_id 
   AND ru.date = r.date 
   AND ru.meter <= r.meter 
   AND ru.maxrent >= r.maxrent
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = ru.user_id;

 +---------+--------+------------+--------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
 | city_id | street | homenumber | date   | meter | maxrent | user_id | firstname | lastname | email  |
 +---------+--------+------------+--------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
 |       1 | street |        100 | time() |    15 |     300 |       1 | Bob       | Hope     | Email1 |
 |       1 | street |        200 | time() |    25 |     400 |       1 | Bob       | Hope     | Email1 |
 |       1 | street |        200 | time() |    25 |     400 |       2 | John      | Doe      | Email2 |
 +---------+--------+------------+--------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks in advance im going to test it.. i guess "ru" is "u" ... ?

Comment: Okay, many thanks.. it works like magic.. new way to make join query's i didn't understand. thanks for that!